# python panda show mix values INT, STR with proper long INT

Tags: python, pandas

**Update**

I tried the following but it still getting the `5.02401E+16` as string instead of the entire number `50240100011400000`.

[image: strong text]

**Initial Question**

May I know how to handle mix values (int and string) while properly display correct full int value in the same column?

**REFERENCE NO** is the header

How to use panda to properly display the *number* **50240100011400000** instead of **5.02401E+16**. Also I have non-integer value in the same column.

Million thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

We can disable scientific notation in Pandas and Python by setting higher float precision :

```
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.9f' % x)
```

for example after that setting we have this:

```
In [28]: pd.Series(np.random.randn(1))*1000000000
Out[28]: 
0    -757322420.605785987
dtype: float64
```

Comment: I think that's right, very well

Comment: i tried but it didn't make any difference. i use it like this (refer to my edited)